# How to make input data as list objects with same input name in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hook-form

When we click on the Add button, a row is created. And the names of the inputs on these lines are the same. How can I send them as separate objects while submitting the form?

example

```
"stock_items": [
    {
      "product_group": 0,
      "box_quantity": 2147483647,
      "quantity_in_box": 2147483647,
      "single_quantity": 2147483647,
      "cost_per_box": "string",
      "sale_per_box": "string",
      "cost_per_single": "string",
      "sale_per_single": "string"
    },
    {
      "product_group": 0,
      "box_quantity": 2147483647,
      "quantity_in_box": 2147483647,
      "single_quantity": 2147483647,
      "cost_per_box": "string",
      "sale_per_box": "string",
      "cost_per_single": "string",
      "sale_per_single": "string"
    }

  ],
```

Note: I am using React Hook Form

Comment: If you do not have a certain number of input groups and you are going to increment, I think you can dynamically use useFieldArray. If you don't have any incrementing inputs you can solve with the index if it is constant. Does it help with the problem?

Comment: e.g {...register(`stock_items.${index}.product_group`)}